# c# Form - Resizing issue - when you resize, the form will go as small as possible and wont expand again

Tags: c#, winforms, resize

I am experiencing an issue with my c# Form. When I resize the form(using the bottom right corner) , it will automatically go as small as possible, even if I am trying to resize it so that it is bigger.

Once it does this it will not let me resize to its original size and stays really small, it will let me maximize it however but I still get the issue if I "un-maximize".

This is the before picture.
[image]

This is how it looks after I attempt to resize the form.
[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have any code handling a post-resize event?

Comment: Try to reproduce this in a small-as-possible app. I remember seeing this with conflicting (Auto)Size options on Panels/UserControls.

Comment: @Renan
no its literally just a form containing controls at the moment with no events or code behind it.

However earlier I did get the following error when trying to compile, "The item "..." was specified more than once in the "Resources" parameter. Duplicate items are not supported by the "Resources" parameter."

I realized under my Main.cs, there was a Main.resx and a Form.resx. I removed the Form.resx and it would compile again. Do you think this could be to do with it?

Comment: No, I don't think it was that. Do check Henk's comment as well.

Comment: Thanks guys i've fixed it. AutoSizeMode was set "GrowAndShrink", I changed it to "GrowOnly" and it works fine now.

Comment: @Brad - you should post your comment as an answer & accept it.  That makes it easier for others trying to solve the same problem find an answer, and it gives you some rep points.  See the [FAQ] and [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've fixed it. AutoSizeMode was set "GrowAndShrink", I changed it to "GrowOnly" and it works fine now.